# Exporting data from one table into another table with a different structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I would like to apologise any mistake/misunderstanding as English is not my natural language.

Context: I need to pull data stored in one table(actually it is a result of joining two tables) and displaying it in a report. Please find below what I would like to accomplish in order to display the data.

Let say that the source table has the following structure and data in it:
[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMXzr.png)

I would like to have as a result a table with the following structure and data in it:

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrkmb.png)

The result table will always have columns from Sunday till Saturday(3 columns per each day of the week to represent the 3 different values for the day.

I've found a solution to my problem through the use of cursor against the source table to inject data into the result table(temporary table). But I would like to avoid the use of cursors.

P.S. I'm using SQlServer 2014 as dbms and Visual Studio2015 to design the reports.

Comment: whats the logic one should apply converting them into different columns, please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,
       [SUN_nCollects] = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'SUN' THEN nCollects  END),
       [SUN_nDels]     = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'SUN' THEN nDels      END),
       [SUN_%]         = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'SUN' THEN percentage END),
       [MON_nCollects] = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'MON' THEN nCollects  END),
       [MON_nDels]     = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'MON' THEN nDels      END),
       [MON_%]         = MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'MON' THEN percentage END),
       . . . .
FROM   source
GROUP BY code
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating test data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TableName (Code int, percentage int, nCollects int, nDels int, [day] varchar(3))
INSERT INTO #TableName (Code, percentage, nCollects, nDels, [day])
VALUES
('101','100','4','4','SUN')
,('102','100','4','4','SUN')
,('104','100','6','6','MON')
,('101','50','4','8','TUE')
,('102','50','4','8','TUE')
,('104','100','2','2','TUE')
,('105','50','1','2','TUE')
,('106','100','2','2','TUE')
,('106','50','2','4','WED')
```

T-SQL that gives the answer you want;

```
SELECT
a.Code
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'SUN' THEN a.nCollects END),0) SUN_nCollects
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'SUN' THEN a.nDels END),0) SUN_nDels
,CONVERT(int,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'SUN' THEN a.nCollects END),0)/ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'SUN' THEN a.nDels END),1))*100) [SUN%]
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'MON' THEN a.nCollects END),0) MON_nCollects
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'MON' THEN a.nDels END),0) MON_nDels
,CONVERT(int,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'MON' THEN a.nCollects END),0)/ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'MON' THEN a.nDels END),1))*100) [MON%]
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'TUE' THEN a.nCollects END),0) TUE_nCollects
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'TUE' THEN a.nDels END),0) TUE_nDels
,CONVERT(int,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'TUE' THEN a.nCollects END),0)/ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'TUE' THEN a.nDels END),1))*100) [TUE%]
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'WED' THEN a.nCollects END),0) WED_nCollects
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'WED' THEN a.nDels END),0) WED_nDels
,CONVERT(int,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'WED' THEN a.nCollects END),0)/ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.day = 'WED' THEN a.nDels END),1))*100) [WED%]
FROM #TableName a
GROUP BY a.Code
```